# Using array in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3. I have the following:

```
# shop.rb
SHOP_TYPES = %w(cafe restaurant station)

# routes.rb
resources :shops do
  member do
    get :nearby_cafes, :nearby_restaurants, :nearby_stations
  end
end
```

Instead of updating my `routes.rb` everytime I add another member in the `SHOP_TYPES` array, is there anyway to read the array in the `routes.rb`?

Thanks.

Comment: `Shop::SHOP_TYPES` ? So: `get *Shop::SHOP_TYPES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TYPES = :nearby_cafes, :nearby_restaurants, :nearby_stations
 ....
get *TYPES
```

Comment: I don't want to redefine `SHOP_TYPES` to `TYPES`.